# Is there has a max duration parameter in selenium?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I hava a automation case that run on chrome and will run over 3hours, i use selenium run case and use chromedriver provide browser node, on macos, it can run for three hours and end normally， but on windows system, the browser always close unexpectly in about 30 minutes.
There is some code about how to start a chrome browser

```
const chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()
chromeCapabilities.set(
  'goog:chromeOptions', {
    args: [
      '--no-sandbox',
    ],
  },
);
const options = new chrome.Options(chromeCapabilities);
this.driver = await new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('chrome')
.setChromeOptions(options)
.setLoggingPrefs(pref)
.usingServer(url)
.build();
```

And i use browserless project to provide browser node https://github.com/joelgriffith/browserless.git

I have used
`chromeCapabilities.set('max-duration', 120);` and `chromeCapabilities.set('max_duration', 120);` and
`chromeCapabilities.set('maxDuration', 120);`
to test the parametar Whether it will work,
but these all not work.

Comment: Do you see any error?

Comment: At the browserless, it output
0|browserless  | 2019-12-23T15:43:12.561Z browserless:server f982e095de255a1fafb5a847aab8582a: Recording timedout stat.
0|browserless  | 2019-12-23T15:43:12.561Z browserless:webdriver Killing browserDriver and proxy 8252
0|browserless  | 2019-12-23T15:43:12.578Z browserless:server Current workload complete.   So i think it something was caused the timeout error